# How to avoid errors with unit testing a controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a controller. This is my controller:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($q) {
    var callMe = function (user) {
        var pr = $q.defer();
        pr.resolve('Hello ' + user);
        return pr.promise;

        //$timeout(function(){
        //    pr.resolve('Hello ' + user);
        //    return pr.promise;
        //},4000);

    }
    return {callMe: callMe};
});



app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,myService){
    $scope.callService = function(){
        $scope.callMeValue = myService.callMe('lo');
    }
})
```

This is my test:

```
beforeEach(
    inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _myService_, _myServiceTimeout_,$q) {
    myService = _myService_;
    myServiceTimeout = _myServiceTimeout_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        someService: someServiceMock
    });

    someServiceMock.callMe.andReturn($q.when('Ted'));
}));


it('ctrl test', function () {
    $scope.callService();
    expect(myService.callMe).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
TypeError: someServiceMock.callMe.andReturn is not a function
```

and:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

How can I fix this?

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EM1blTOlg5fw5wq6OFcr?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your example contains several bugs.

1. If you use timeout in code, in test you must use $timeout.flush() (scope.$apply not enough)
2. $timeout is promise, you not need create own promise
3. $timeout is promise, you must return it

   ```
   app.factory('myServiceTimeout', function ( $timeout) {
       var callMe = function (user) {
           return $timeout(function(){
               return 'Hello ' + user;
           },4000);

       }
       return {callMe: callMe};
   });


   it('test2',function(){
       var result;
       myServiceTimeout.callMe('Ruud').then(function(ret)
       {
           result = ret;
       });

       $timeout.flush()
       expect(result).toBe('Hello Ruud');
   });
   ```

whole exemple: http://plnkr.co/edit/cqzTYwfs94Xqyz5MTxeE?p=preview